# h3 text not visible

Tags: html, css

I have some text in h3 tag, but the text is not visible, I have tried changing the height of the h3 tag as well of the div containing it.
The text I am talking about is visible in screenshot here - http://imagebin.org/226001
& the web page is here at - http://bit.ly/PLDSCJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the container divs on you page is clipping that part out.
It is most probably the div with .details_wrapper class that has just 200px as height.
Either align those hheights properly or set overflow to visible

Answer (score 2):

It's because the parent elements (`.detail` , `.details` and `.details_wrapper`) all have a fixed height. The H3 will be placed inside those elements, so when it's bigger you'll not see it.

Solution is to change the height of the parent elements.

Comment: In this case, you only need to change the height of `.details_wrapper` actually.

Answer (score 2):

try to increase the height of

```
<div class="details_wrapper">
```

something like this...

```
.details_wrapper{
 height:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper is not high enough, specifically

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
<div class="carousel clearfix" style="position:absolute;">
<div class="panel">
<div class="details_wrapper">
```

This container cuts off your text. When you change to height to something more, say 400px; your text reappears! It is situated in this part of your CSS:

```
.carousel .panel .details_wrapper {
    height: 400px; /* changed this height */
    left: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 175px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the height in your details_wrapper

Just add:

> style="height: 400px"

And the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use some color other than White.

```
<h3 class="Lexia-Bold" style="color:black; overflow: auto; width: 100px; height:500px;">
```